# How to randomly format using Sass

Tags: sass

I recently switched from CSS to Sass, and have been running into issues (which are almost certainly my fault) involving randomly positioning images.

Here is the (quite short) HTML:

```html
<div id="imgholder"></div>
```

And here is the Sass:

```
@import "compass";

$s-min: 20;
$s-max: 70;
$l-min: 30;
$l-max: 90;

#imgholder {
  position: absolute;
}

@for $i from 1 through 1000 {
  #imgholder:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    left: random(500) + px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is running well and compoles the CSS correct ... but there is one issue:

Creating multiple selectors by an `ID` - in this case `#imgholder:nth-child(...)` leads to wrong code and maybe inconsistent layout as a selector on a page HAS TO BE UNIQUE.

Use a class instead: `.imgholder:nth-child(...)` ...

Additional note: maybe it is not a good idea to fix place 1.000 random elements by 1.000 random classes on a page. That's a task which is better done in JS.

If you would ask for your concrete target (what you want to do on your page?) with a little code example I believe there will be some answers ... ;-)

Comment: thank you so much! I'm extremely new to sass, and your post helped me out a lot.

Comment: by the way, I just put in a random number for Stack Overflow example. I am actually only doing 5 different random elements.